# Custom Charts in Community with Lightning Components (ChartJS)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I have previously been using ChartJS to generate a dashboard in a custom community using Lightning Components.  It appears that the Spring 17 release does not like the ChartJS library.  I get 2 separate errors, one for each chart I'm generating.

For a bar chart I'm using, I get a "str.replace is not a function" when trying to generate the chart.

For a Pie chart I'm using, I get a popup error in builder when I try to generate the legend: 'Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src *".'

So, 2 questions:
1. Is anyone else seeing this?
2. What alternative JS libraries are you using for custom charts in communities?

Comment: Have you experienced any issues with ChartJS components breaking between page changes? I have the same component on two different pages. They both work fine when I refresh to load each page. But when I click a community navigation link and the page uses the single-page-app version of navigation, all the ChartJS components will break. Any ideas what this is or how to fix it?

Comment: I should add that no JS errors appear in the console from Aura or standard JS. If I attempt to fire any ChartJS api events on the chart object (which does actually get created), the API reacts, but doesn't repaint any elements on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using ChartJS 2.1.4 under LockerService with no known issues. What version are you using?

The second error about unsafe-eval is because it violates the CSP unsafe-eval requirement (eval is not supported in any form). This has been part of the published Lightning Security requirements that are now enforced in Spring'17:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_csp.htm

Comment: Hmm, I upgraded to 2.4 and keep getting a "Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item".  Looks like I'll need to open another question.  None of the 4 variations for defining ctx from http://www.chartjs.org/docs/ seem to be working.

Comment: @JasonBenkert this looks to be an issue with Locker's implementation of SecureElement.getContext() - should return an instance of CanvasRenderingContext2D and its returning the generic wrapper Locker creates as a fallback. We will get this fixed asap.

Comment: Created bug W-3624260 to track this and we'll get it triaged/fixed - no workaround currently. Sorry for the inconvenience.